# jQuery resizable(), accessing the original object

Tags: jquery, resizable

This may seem like an obvious thing, but I can't find it. When using resizable, I want to save the new width of the image, but how do I access the ID attribute of the image that I have just resized? This is my code:

```
$('img.article_image').resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    handles: "se",
    stop: function(event, ui){
        // Here I want to access the ID attribute
        // of the img.article_image I am resizing
}});
```

So, the ui object has ui.helper, which I can't use. I.e. ui.helper.attr("id") or $(ui.helper).attr("id") are both undefined. I can't use $(this).attr("id") either, but I *CAN* use $(this).width() to see the new width, so it's very odd.

What am I doing wrong? When using draggable() I seem to be able to access $(this) the correct way, but not with resizable... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the ui parameter holds the resized element

```
stop: function(event, ui){
 alert(ui.originalElement[0].id);
}
```

Comment: This was (semi-)correct, this will fetch the correct ID:

<code>$(ui.originalElement[0]).attr("id")</code>

Comment: If this is meant to be used then someone should add this to the documentation at the jQuery UI site. I'm not sure if I would feel comfortable using an undocumented property as it could go away in a future version

Comment: @Sandman - actually just `ui.originalElement.attr("id")` would suffice. The `ui.originalElement[0]` notation is used to pull a DOM object out of it's jQuery wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the resizeable plugin but if it follows the same guidelines as the built-in jQuery events then `this` will be a reference to the affected DOM element. So you can get a jQuery wrapped object like so:

```
$('img.article_image').resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    handles: "se",
    stop: function(event, ui){
        var img = $(this);
        var id = img.attr("id");
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could just get the ID inside of `stop` callback with this code:

```
$('img.article_image').attr('id');
```

This will however duplicate the selector but parameters passed by `stop` callback function doesn't have the record of the original object that was resized.

Comment: This will not work if there are multiple images with the `.article_image` class